# .htaccess password protect all but one page

Tags: htaccess, password

Hi I would like to password protect my entire Wordpress site using .htaccess. All pages except one page which would be viewable to the public. I know there are other methods out there built into wordpress but I would like to have all pages except the one protected using the .htaccess method.

How do I make that one page viewable without a password?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .htaccess file *after* your password protection on the entire site:

```
<Files "page.php">
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```